# undefined method `include?' for #<Pathname:/public/system/:attachment/:style/:filename>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-5

i want to upgrade a rails application to rails 5.1 and ruby 2.4.0

i have this error when i want to delete 
(undefined method `include?' for #)

this is my action in graphic_creation_file_controller

```
def delete
@graphic_creation_file = GraphicCreationFile.find(params[:id])
gc_id = @graphic_creation_file.graphic_creation_id
if @graphic_creation_file.destroy
  flash[:notice] = 'Data was successfully deleted.'
  redirect_to :controller => :graphic_creation_file, :action => :list, :graphic_creation_id => gc_id
else
  flash[:error] = 'Data was NOT successfully deleted.'
  redirect_to :controller => :graphic_creation_file, :action => :list, :graphic_creation_id => gc_id
end
end
```

this is my view

```
   <%= link_to "New Comment", {:controller => :comment, :action => :new, :graphic_creation_file_id => file},{ :class=>"btn btn-success" , :role=>"button" } %>
      <div style="margin: 2px 0;"></div>
      <%= link_to "Edit", {:controller => :graphic_creation_file, :action => :edit, :id => file},{ :class=>"btn btn-primary" , :role=>"button" } %>
      <div style="margin: 2px 0;"></div>
      <%= link_to "Delete", {:controller => :graphic_creation_file, :action => :delete, :id => file},{:confirm => 'Are you sure?', :class=>"btn btn-danger" , :role=>"button" } %>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

the application use paperclip gem for the file i want to delete

this is my model graghic_creation_file.rb

```
has_attached_file :eps,:path => Rails.root.join('/public/system/:attachment/:style/:filename')
validates_attachment_content_type :eps, content_type: ['image/x-eps' ]  
has_attached_file :png, :styles => { :medium => '600x800>', :thumb => '150x200>' }
```

why this ((undefined method `include?')) thnx

Comment: Try `:path => Rails.root.join(..).to_s`. Also, you have a logic error: `('/public` => `('public`. And finally, you can use `path: ':rails_root/public...'` as in readme of Paperclip.

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly :)

Comment: Pavel, why don't you add your comment as an answer since it's the correct one?